# Propel with oci8

Tags: propel, oci8

I'm using symfony 1.4.3 with propel 1.4.1 on an Oracle database, and I have issues with blob types. I was aware that the oracle pdo (pdo_oci) was experimental, and it seems that has not improved. I've been looking for ways to use propel with oci8, but I think that is not supported, nor the latest versions.

Is there any class that implements the Propel data access with oci8?

I'm considering using Symfony2 with Doctrine, which I think is compatible with oci8, but I have to update all my code.

Comment: Did you try with propel 1.6? It seems to have few improvment with Oracle.